# Is there a way to find the width of the page using jinja2

Tags: django, jinja2

I am using a django framework and wanted to display another image on screen if the width of the screen is less than 800px (similar to the CSS '@media(min-width)' function). Is it possible to do it with jinja2 or can we do something in the django views to find the width of the page...

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I think you can't do that with jinja2. It should handle with css or javascript.

Comment: Jinja/Django's template language, etc. are rendered at the *server* side. So it does not know (much) about the client.

Comment: aiyooo, that sucks. Anyways thanks a lot for your help and support